# simple code for modifying nested list in dict

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am using a dict in python which has the following content, basiclly it has a nested list in value set, now I want to modify the nested list.

```
insn = { "pop":[1,["operand1 = [esp]", "esp = esp + 4"]]}
```

Here is what I am doing

```
for k,v in insn.items():
    for i, s in enumerate(v):
        v[1][i] = s.replace("old", "new")
    insn.update({k:v})
```

The code is pretty messed, I wonder if there is a simple way to do this ?

Comment: If this works, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so where is `old` that you want to replace it with `new` , also your code raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: This `[1,["operand1 = [esp]", "esp = esp + 4"]]` looks really weird, why did you make it like this?

Comment: this `v[1][i]` looks wrong. I think it should be `v[i][1]`. Unless you should actually enumerate on `v[1]`

Comment: Actually, I want to build some formulas which represent this instruction. For example, "pop operand1" first fill the register with esp, then increase esp by 4. That's why I have a nested list keeping these expressions. And the first attribute in the outer list is the number of operand. So now all I need to do is to replace the operand with actul register.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do here. But supposing you want to change `esp` or some other string within the embedded list you can do something like this:

```
for k, v in insn.items():
    for i in range(len(v[1])):
        v[1][i] = v[1][i].replace('esp', 'new_esp')
    insn.update({k:v})
```

now you get:

```
>>> insn
{'pop': [1, ['operand1 = [new_esp]', 'new_esp = new_esp + 4']]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code did exactlly what I want, but I guess maybe this code be simplified into one line. Just want to figure it out.